# Как исправить ошибку когда запушккаeш код

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last
 raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000014C18DCEC10>
Traceback (most recent call last
  raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Process finished with exit code 1):):):]
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проверить алгоритм авторизации и данные авторизации. (читайте ошибку)

Comment: В ошибке написано, что неправильный токен передали

Answer (score 0):

самая нижняя строка `bot.run('token')` необходимо вставить свой api token, вместо `token`, ошибка `401 Unauthorized` говорит сама за себя, что ты передаешь невалидный токен

Comment: Там Вставлен токен просто не читає